# reading line skips every other line

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml

I'm making a small program that basically loads from a txt file. The txt file has the following data:

```
    NAME1, xx, xx, xx, xx (Where XX are numbers)  
    NAME2, xx, xx, xx, xx  
    etc...
```

There is no set end to this file as it can be edited later to add additional names.
The code I have to read it is as follows:

```
private void doLoadProfile() {
    String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "profiles.txt";
    System.out.println(filePath);

    try {
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
       while (in.readLine() != null) {
          displayLog.appendText(in.readLine() + "\n");
       }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        displayLog.appendText("\n Error: file not found" + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        displayLog.appendText("\n Error: " + e.toString());
    }   
}
```

However this only outputs every other line, for some reason it's skipping lines (I have a txt file with 4 lines and I only get the 2nd and 4th line). I tried adding additional 2 lines and again, only got 2nd, 4th and 6th.

Comment: Each `readLine` call traverse to next line and returns it, also one in your `while` condition. You need to read it once, store in variable and use variable when needed. Now where is that duplicate (googling for `java readline skips lines` possibly with `site:stackoverflow.com` for results from this site).

Comment: Well, you're calling readLine() twice at each iteration. Don't. Call it once, store the result in a variable, check if it's null, then append it. Or just use readAllLines (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-)

Answer (score 4):

You're calling in.readLine() twice (once in the while statement, which reads the first line, and again in the appendText, which reads the second line). Cache the value in the while statement in a String, and use that later instead.